# Webdriver.io elements usage

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io

I want to iterate over element and do some thing on all of them, e.g. set values etc. For now i have following code, but i cant even get attribute from selected elements.

```
 client.elements("freeforms-widget").then(function (elems) {
           for (let elem of elems.value) {
             let k =  client.elementIdAttribute(elem.ELEMENT,'name');
             console.log(k);
          }
        })
```

And all i see is following :

```
{ state: 'pending' }
{ state: 'pending' }
{ state: 'pending' }
{ state: 'pending' }
{ state: 'pending' }
{ state: 'pending' }
```

The elems itself seems to be fine

```
{ state: 'success',
  sessionId: 'dd301839-369a-45a2-a38c-4bb8ce0a439b',
  hCode: 1204992695,
  value:
   [ { ELEMENT: '0' },
     { ELEMENT: '1' },
     { ELEMENT: '2' },
     { ELEMENT: '3' },
     { ELEMENT: '4' },
  ....
```

What i'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`elementIdAttribute()` returns a *promise* - `{ state: 'pending' }` is a string representation of a non-resolved pending promise. To have a real value printed on the console you need to resolve the promise:

```
client.elementIdAttribute(elem.ELEMENT,'name').then(function (k) {
  console.log(k);
});
```

Comment: while this works, it isn't ideal. It means when comparing elements to each other we have to write code with lots of callbacks.